# Melding in American Canasta

Tags: canasta

In modern American canasta a meld of 180 is needed to meld. You can meld with enough points but have only one card left to discard. The card is a wild card. Is this acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

You must have at least 2 Canastas in order to go out, so if you do not have that then you cannot meld all but 1 card since you have to discard a card to end your turn.

> You can go out if you can satisfy both of the following conditions:
>
> > 1. your team has completed two canastas, and
> > 2. you are able to meld all but one of your cards and discard your last card.
>
> If you do not satisfy the conditions for going out, you are not allowed to leave yourself without any cards at the end of your turn: you must play in such a way as to keep at least one card after discarding.

https://www.pagat.com/rummy/canasta.html#american

Answer (score 0):

Although Gendolkari didn't say this explicitly, your final discard card is allowed to be a wild card if that is what's needed to meld the rest of your cards.  There is no rule stating that a card is not allowed to be discarded at any point in a hand.